# Azure Custom Domain from 3rd party Registrar

Tags: azure, dns, azure-web-app-service

As part of my Azure learning, I am trying to configure Azure with a Domain Name purchased with GoDaddy.

I am following the following Azure Articles:

- [Map a custom domain name to an Azure app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-custom-domain-name#a)
- [Configure a custom domain name in Azure App Service (Purchased directly from GoDaddy)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-godaddy-custom-domain-name)

Questions/issues:

1. The article references making a TXT record that references `<appname>.azurewebsites.net`.  Has `<appname>.cloudapp.net` replaced this?
2. The article references a "Custom Domains Blade in the Azure Portal".  When I go to "Web Apps" on the old Azure Portal, it redirects me to the new one.

In the new `portal.azure.com` I cannot find a place to specify a Custom Domain anywhere.

3. Here is what my GoDaddy DNS looks like, does it look right?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work.

I just kitchen-sinked it.  Not sure if `cloudapp.net` or `azurewebsites.net` is needed so I put in both.

I also set up Active Directory with a custom domain (the additional TXT entry)

[image]

Comment: is it just for an azure website? then azurewebsite.net. if you are doing stuff with VM then cloudapp.net is need. and if you are doing both azurewebsites and VM, then add both.